# HP Color Laser 150nw - prints the text on top of the page again at the bottom

Tags: printer, hp

I am using HP Color Laser 150nw, it prints the some sort of blurry characters from top of the page again at the bottom, I don't know how to troubleshoot this or which part should be replaced, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the paper size is correctly set in the printer's configuration?

Comment: looks like a mechanical issue ... talk to the HP technical support

Comment: What type of paper are you using? Make sure it is plain bond paper.